# How to fade out text using JavaScript or jQuery and then bring it back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript/jQuery and what I want to do is to fade out text and when the opacity is zero, I want to bring back the text with the same effect. I am leaning towards some kind of if statement and the fade in effect, but don't manage to understand how to put it all together. Any tips for how this could be done using jQuery would be appreciated.

```js
function hideText() {
  var fadeText = document.getElementById("fadeTextp");
  fadeText.style.opacity = 0;
  fadeText.addEventListener("transitionend", function(e) {
    alert("The text is hidden, but how can I now get it back with same effect?")
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<p id="fadeTextp" class="fade" onclick="hideText();">
  Fade out this text and then bring it back when clicked again.
</p>
```

Comment: You can do this with `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` in jQuery. I see you have a JavaScript example. Which are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jQuery example since you asked for jQuery. You need a container with some height to be able to click again for the text to come back. If you don't have this container then the thing you add a "click" event listener to is not available to click anymore.

I use the `:visible` selector to see if the text is visible and if so `fadeOut` and if it's not visible then `fadeIn`.

```js
let fadeTextp = $("#fadeTextp");
$("#fadeTextContainer").on("click", () => {
  if (fadeTextp.is(":visible")) {
    fadeTextp.fadeOut()
  } else {
    fadeTextp.fadeIn()
  }
});
```

```css
#fadeTextContainer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fadeTextContainer">
  <p id="fadeTextp">
    Fade out this text and then bring it back when clicked again.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your overall goal is, but there are lots of ways to do this kind of thing. Some could use only CSS, some could use JavaScript, some could use both. I'll do a "both" example.

Note: It would probably be better to use one or the other - so you don't define the transition time in both places.

Note: jQuery has animation support built in. See the answer from @Twisty for a jQuery example and links to their docs.

```js
var transitionTime = 2250;
var faderTimeout = null; // keep track of this to cancel it if multiple events happen
var fadeText = document.getElementById("fadeTextp");

function hideText() {
    fadeText.classList.remove('out');   
    fadeText.classList.add('out');
    window.clearTimeout(faderTimeout);

    faderTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
        fadeText.classList.remove('out');
    }, transitionTime);
}
```

```css
.fade {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2.25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2.25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade.out {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<p id="fadeTextp" class="fade" onclick="hideText();">
    Fade out this text and then bring it back when clicked again.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick jQuery Example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".fade").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeOut(600, function() {
      $this.fadeIn(600);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="fadeTextp" class="fade">
  Fade out this text and then bring it back when clicked again.
</p>
```

This uses `.fadeOut()` and cascades a callback to `.fadeIn()`.

See more:

- https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/
- https://api.jquery.com/fadein/

You can also animate the visibility.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".fade").click(function(e) {
    var t = $(this);
    if (t.hasClass("out")) {
      t.animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 600);
      t.removeClass("out");
    } else {
      t.animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, 600);
      t.addClass("out");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="fadeTextp" class="fade">Fade out this text and then bring it back when clicked again.</p>
```